# Referencing self.frame in let statements in UIView

Tags: cocoa, swift

In ObjC, for iOS, I used to use a bunch of `#define` statements at the top of a class file to set constants for view layout. Usually, they referenced `self.frame`. I'm trying to do the same with `let` statements in Swift, and it won't let me use `self.frame` anywhere. I get errors because the `frame` property cannot be found:

```
import UIKit

class MySubview: UIView {

    /* Constants */
    let frameX = (self.frame.origin.x) // error
    let frameY = (self.frame.origin.y) // error
    let frameW = (self.frame.size.width) // error 
    let frameH = (self.frame.size.height) // error
    // ...
}
```

Why is it complaining? I'm subclassing `UIView`, so the property should be there. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there are in fact not constants because the frame can change. The value of a constant property (using `let`) is set in the initialisation stage before access to `self` is allowed, and cannot be changed.

In your case, you should be using [computed properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html):

```
class MySubview: UIView {
    var frameX: CGFloat { return frame.minX }
    var frameY: CGFloat { return frame.minY }
    var frameW: CGFloat { return frame.width }
    var frameH: CGFloat { return frame.height }
    // ...
}
```

Also, note the more convenient methods on `CGRect` in Swift, which might make some of these convenience variables somewhat redundant.

Comment: This works except that it wants me to explicitly define the type for computer properties, so I made it `frameX:CGFloat`, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I wasn't at my computer when I wrote the answer. I've updated it with the explicit types.